# Access denied when creating registry key

Tags: c#, registry, access-denied

I am trying to create a registry key at following location but I am getting access denied error:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyProgram

Here is the code:

```
RegistryKey reg;
reg = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyProgram");
```

Comment: Probably the user that is executing your code actually does not have the permissions to create the key. If you manually start `regedit` with the same user, can you create the subkey in the Registry Editor?

Comment: @UweKeim
I am logged in as administrator. But when I run regedit then I get that message from Windows "Do you want to allow the program to make changes to the computer?" and when I press Yes only then I can access registry. And yes I can create key and subkey through registry editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most likely using [User Account Control (UAC)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). This means that even if you are an administrator your access token doesn't have the necessary privileges to do things like creating registry keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

However, by going through a UAC prompt you can elevate your privileges.

Regedit includes a [UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) that will raise the prompt before it is executed ensuring that it can perform the actions it needs to be able to do. You can also right-click on an executable or shortcut and select *Run as administrator*.

So essentially you have three options:

- Turn off UAC
- Use *Run as administrator*
- Include a UAC manifest in your executable

The first solution is less secure and the last solution is the most elegant (but also the one that actually requires some effort).

Comment: My solution to write to HKLM was to "Run as administrator" on a spinoff process from the same executable (passing an argument so that the exe would do something different). However, I also had to set the Platform target setting to "Any CPU" instead of "x86".

Comment: @DanW: When you set the platform target to _Any CPU_ on .NET 4.0 and execute your application on a 64 bit operating system the process will be a 64 bit process. This means that your application sees the "real" registry. If it executes in a 32 bit process the process sees a modified version of the registry and that is probably why you have to change the platform target.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run your application under an account that has sufficient privileges to write to the registry at the specified location. Usually the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch is reserved for power users because it contains machine global settings.

Comment: I am logged in as administrator. But when I run regedit then I get that message from Windows "Do you want to allow the program to make changes to the computer?" and when I press Yes only then I can access registry.

Comment: @Ali, so you have to run your application as Administrator, exactly the same way you are doing with regedit. You right click on the executable and select Run As administrator.

Comment: @Ali - just because you are logged in as admin, your apps do not run at that privilege level automatically, you have to get them to request elevated privileges.

Comment: @slugster
And how do I do that in C#?

Comment: You can't do that in C#. It's the user running your application that must start it as administrator. All you can do is include a manifest in your application so that when the user starts it, it prompts for elevating privileges.

Comment: You can do that in C# by adding a Application Manifest File and then un-comment the following line: <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: @Darin, He could restart his process using the runas verb, or he could use a secondary process to do the work where the out of process would be invoked by a UAC button (this is the recommended pattern anyway). Given the task he needs to perform, this doesn't mean his entire process should run elevated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below syntax:

```
SETX /S [Machine Name] [Variable] [Value] /M
```

I am not sure why but in Windows 7, if you specify machine name on which you are adding system variable, even for local machine then it works.