# C# Associate midi file

Tags: c#, wpf, associations, midi, associate

I'm trying to associate midi files with my c# application
And I got the following exception , can anyone tell me why?
My code:

```
public static void Associate()
{
    RegistryKey FileReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\.mid");
    RegistryKey AppReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\Applications\\MyApp.exe");
    RegistryKey AppAssoc = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.mid");

    //FileReg.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "image_path");
    FileReg.CreateSubKey("PerceivedType").SetValue("", "Bytes");

    AppReg.CreateSubKey("shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\" %1");
    AppReg.CreateSubKey("shell\\edit\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\" %1");
    //AppReg.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "image_path"); 

    AppAssoc.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("Progid", "Applications\\MyApp.exe");

    SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Exception come from the call:

```
AppAssoc.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("Progid", "Applications\\MyApp.exe");
```

> Additional information: Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.mid\UserChoice'
>   is denied.

Anyone can tell me what do to ?

Comment: Are you running the application as Administrator?

Comment: No, That will fix it for me? , How should I do it? @Alex

Comment: you need to have elevated rights to perform registry edits. Cannot guarantee but it should do the trick. Right click application executable (or Visual Studio icon if running inside of it) and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Its not working @Alex

Comment: did you find the option to run as administrator? How do you run your program?

Comment: I've run the VS as administration , also tried to run the MyApp.exe program as adminstrator @Alex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99810/discussion-between-alex-and-dbs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied when creating registry key in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151771/access-denied-when-creating-registry-key-in-c-sharp)