# How to create registry key in c#

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I am trying to create registry but can't. I change the permission and manually I can create it, but I want to create it using C#.

Here is my code:

```
 RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\\{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}\\Shell\\Unlock\\command");
            key.SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

I can add it manually by changing the permission but it does not work in C#

[image: 1]

Comment: 1.) Did you do any research?  This is very well documented and I'm sure there are plenty of articles and posts out there to help you with your problem. 2.) what is that picture supposed to be?  It doesn't have anything to do with the registry.

Comment: yes i researched but i can't found with c#, manually i just change the permission and its done... with c# i can't read delete key from shell

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;  
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");  
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");  
key.Close();
```

Comment: {"Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}\\shellex\\unlock\\command' is denied."}

Comment: Take a look at [access to the registry key is denied When i want update the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639084/access-to-the-registry-key-is-denied-when-i-want-update-the-value).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)