# Access to registry key is denied

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to set the value of a Registry key programmatically :

```
string keyname = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{ea7039cb-389f-4405-8497-b33ab9ff63d8}\Properties";

//GetValue works - the path is fine
var value = Registry.GetValue(keyname, "{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2", null);

//Access denied exception
Registry.SetValue(keyname, "{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2", "test");
```

I'm starting Visual Studio as Administrator.
I've even added a manifest file to force the execution as Administrator.

When I try to modify the value using Regedit, it works.

Anybody has an idea of what is going on ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does also your application run as administrator, or only Visual Studio?

Comment: are you sure you followed every step from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639296/4062197

Comment: yes I followed the steps. As I explained. I FORCED the application to run as Admininistor via the manifest, I also start visual studio as adminstrator. I even tried to explicitely start the application as administrator. Nothing works. However when I use Regedit I can change the value of the key, without getting prompted by UAC at any time.