# C# Give permission to the registry

Tags: c#, registry

I did on the `Form1_Load` a code that modifies a registry value. But when i open the compiled Form1, i get "Access to the registry key is denied" error. How can i do on `Form1_Load` to get permission in the specified location? The location is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}`. I also tried to run the Form1 as administrator. Maybe i'm missing some privilleges to do that. I can manually change permissions in the registry using Properties, etc, but how do i change the permissions to modify the selected location using code?
The code is

```
        RegistryKey key;
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}");
        key.SetValue("RunAs", "Interactive User");
```

Comment: Your running code doesn't have permission to make a particular change but you think adding more code will allow it to first change its permissions to do so. Wouldn't that break the concept of permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151771/access-denied-when-creating-registry-key would that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
    RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Registry64).CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}", true);
    key.SetValue("RunAs", "Interactive User");
```

and make sure that your program has requireAdministrator perm in your app manifest.